# How to thanks someone for taking time in the past

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to send a thank you letter to my boss, is below correct?

> When I look back at the past year sure I will remember, how you have took from your time and effort to my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look back at the past year, I am sure I will remember how you gave of your time and all your efforts to help me.